# How to use realm 2.2.0-Snapshot

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, realm

I try to evaluate the performance of the Realm database for a specific project.
Everything works fine at the moment. I just miss one method. I need a function to get the needed space for storing my realm database.

In case of some other databases I can take the size of the files where it is stored in. How can I get the needed space for my specific realm database?

And more important for me is the version. Evertything I tried works just fine with version 0.88.0
 I just need to add the following dependency to my modules gradle file.

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    provided 'io.realm:realm-android:0.80.0'
    ...
}
```

If I change this to

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    provided 'io.realm:realm-android:2.2.0'
    ...
}
```

I got the following error:

Error:(24, 13) Failed to resolve: io.realm:realm-android:2.2.0-snapshot

How can I change to the newest version?

Because of debugging I got version 2.1.0 working for me. Hope that I can copy the classes of the TestProject to my bigger Evaluation Project without getting errors. If not I will report that.

But first, I need some code to get the needed diskspace for storing the whole database. I need this to compare it to other Databases.

Comment: According to their documentation (https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/) the latest version is 2.1.0

Comment: Version 0.8? That's really outdated...  https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#installation

Comment: @nbokmans There's a 2.2.0 snapshot build on Github, but probably requires JitPack to get it at the moment

Comment: The size of your database depends on your quantity of data.

Comment: `provided`? I'm surprised this ever worked.

Comment: after change to version 2.1.0 I just got another error. But Thanks for this hint.
new Error is to big for a comment, so i will attach a link to a txt file

https://www.dropbox.com/s/8b3arbkaf0w2w67/RealmError.txt?dl=0

Comment: Consider doing a clean rebuild and disabling instant run

Comment: Hello @EpicPandaForce,
I just delete the whole build folder in my project workspace. After that I opened Android Studio and choose Build->clean from menu. If I try too run I still got the same errors like before.

And I go to Settings-> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Instant run and check off the first line "Enable Instant run to hot swap code/resource changes on deploy(default enabled)"  before I tried to run.

Comment: I will post my gradle Files for Realm Version 2.1.0 here with Links to my DropBox. @EpicPandaForce


Project Gradle File: [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ka6y39c2flo1snd/build.gradle%20project%20.txt?dl=0)


module gradle File: [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hvebgyqwhj9etgy/build.gradle%20module%20.txt?dl=0)

Error Messages: [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/411mocrb0e4jwxo/Error%20Message.txt?dl=0)


Gradle Console Output: [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/f4stsipo3408yk4/gradle%20console.txt?dl=0)

Comment: You look like you're tinkering with package-internal API that no longer exists.

Comment: What do you mean @EpicPandaForce ?     what should I change?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce
For Debugging I opened a new Project. Just with an empty Activity. 
First I changed the gradle Files to use Realm 2.1.0.
Everything works fine.

After that I try to get a realmDefault Instance. 
but this doesn't work because I got an Exception [see here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dtae5rho8r7gylo/RealmNewTestException.txt?dl=0).

You can see the whole project [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/u22nfhbn7jz8jsw/RealmNewTest.zip?dl=0)

Comment: Ahh. I found that I have to call 
    Realm.init(dbctx); 
before calling 
    realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();

After this my new Project RealmNewTest works fine. But If I change this in my old Project, it still doesn't work. I dunno why, because I copied all my classes from the old project to the new project. 
So  I got version 2.1.0 working for me.

Answer (score 0):

To use Realm's SNAPSHOT version, you need to add their snapshot repository in your build gradle.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'http://oss.jfrog.org/artifactory/oss-snapshot-local'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:<version>-SNAPSHOT"
    }
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'http://oss.jfrog.org/artifactory/oss-snapshot-local'
    }
}
```

To use Realm in your project, you need to apply it as a Gradle plugin (since 0.88.0).

```
apply plugin: 'realm-android'
```

For more info, refer to the official documentation: https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#installation

Comment: I tried this. You can see my gradle Files with the following hyperlinks.


project build gradle:https://www.dropbox.com/s/y3siwyj9f5ideuy/build.gradle%20project%20.txt?dl=0


module Build gradle: https://www.dropbox.com/s/6mluttn07zvd5bc/build.gradle%20module.txt?dl=0


ErrorMessage:https://www.dropbox.com/s/fr6qu1fdm5nnavh/version%202-2-0-snapshot%20ERROR.txt?dl=0

Comment: oh, my mistake.  Now it is filled.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `-SNAPSHOT` part from the version and its actually `2.1.1` is the latest version as for now, so the main part should be

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:2.1.1"
    }
}
```

They really have some issue with the realm-annotations-processor of version 2.2.0-SNAPSHOT ([its missing, check here](https://oss.jfrog.org/oss-snapshot-local/io/realm/realm-annotations-processor/)). The latest version they did provide is 2.0.2-SNAPSHOT and thus if you want to use the SNAPSHOT then you should use 2.0.2-SNAPSHOT version.